# Curl is not working from a https site

Tags: php, curl, https

I have a web service(WSL) hosted in window server(HTTP only).

And my website is hosted in linux server with ssl (https)

If i use curl to GET / POST data to my web service (WSL) from linux server domain with HTTPS its not working.

It's throwing a error "couldn't connect to the host".

But if i try to POST / GET data to my web service from my local machine curl is working.

Here is my code can any one suggest what is the problem:

$ch = curl_init('service domain');

```
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json_data );  
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                      
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
            'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
            'Content-Length: ' . strlen($json_data)   
        ));                                                                          
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        echo curl_error($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
```

Do any one face the same issue before.

Answer (score 0):

> "couldn't connect to the host"

This means that the site is not reachable by https. 
Since https is used on a different port then http it can mean that https is either not probably set up on the server (check with `netstat -nlt` on the linux system if it is listening on 0.0.0.0:443, 127.0.0.1:443 is not enough) or that there is a firewall in between blocking the connections.